# "react native pushnotificationIOS "scheduleLocalNotification" firedate object format

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native

Does anyone know the date and time format for the "fireDate" object of the "PushNotificationIOS" method "scheduleLocalNotification"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I got the following error message when sending a wrong string to `fireDate`:

```
Expected format: YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

If no other format works I suggest the one above, the following code works using moment:

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")
```

Comment: Using `Date()`did not work but `moment` trick is better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.m#L37), you can see that the format is NSDate.

This being said, multiple formats work. I have tested all of the formats [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and they work like a charm.

```
var today = new Date();
var date = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var date = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var date = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var date = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old string, but just for the record, moment format for fractional seconds (milliseconds) is caps on the last three s'es ergo moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')